# JavaScript list key and mouse event hooks

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get a list of what JavaScripts if any have hooks on key presses or mouse clicks?

I am using a CMS that has a handy richt click menu and keyboard shortcuts that at times I find very annoying and would like to add a script in that disables then when I need them disabled.

I have been searching for this all day but I cannot seem to find anything about this. Probably cause of conflicting results with how to capture clicks and keys :)

Comment: If you know what the bind event is you can just create a function that unbinds them and one to bind them if you want.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you can find this out with the browser itself. Using Chrome, if you right-click an element and select "Inspect element", you'll be taken to the dev-tools. If you close the "Styles" accordion entry on the right and then open "Event Listeners", you can see all events that are being handled for a particular element. I'd expect to find handlers for the click/key events you mention on either the document node or the window node.

Comment: I want to be able to get them, record them into a variable and put them back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only achieve this on node level, not globally.

You can override inline events by setting them to `null`:

```
var node = document.getElementById('foo');
node.onclick = null;
```

Libraries like jQuery that implement `bind` or some other form of event listener registration usually define an `unbind` method also.